# UGC Post Image media order not respected

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm creating an UGC post with mediaCategory IMAGE and multiple images attached uploaded with the recommended Assets Api.

I've noticed that LinkedIn does not respect the original order we are sending through.

Has anyone experienced this as well or has any idea what I'm missing?

```
{
    "author": "urn:li:organization:5590506",
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
    "specificContent": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
            "media": [
                {
                    "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:ID1",
                    "status": "READY",
                    "title": {
                        "attributes": [],
                        "text": "Asset 1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:ID2",
                    "status": "READY",
                    "title": {
                        "attributes": [],
                        "text": "Asset 2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:ID3",
                    "status": "READY",
                    "title": {
                        "attributes": [],
                        "text": "Asset 3"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:ID4",
                    "status": "READY",
                    "title": {
                        "attributes": [],
                        "text": "Asset 4"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:ID5",
                    "status": "READY",
                    "title": {
                        "attributes": [],
                        "text": "Asset 5"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "shareCommentary": {
                "attributes": [],
                "text": "Some share text"
            },
            "shareMediaCategory": "IMAGE"
        }
    },
    "visibility": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Hello @gregory , May I know how did you upload image in UGC APIs. I am trying to upload this but not getting any success

Comment: Honestly just by following the public api docs. My issue was unrelated to the LinkedIn API as it turned out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Gregory, I resolved my issue after some time actually I was not sending my images in binary format but I sending it.

Answer (score 0):

POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts

I think you want to maintain the order of media in single post.
But I see same media ID "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5500AQG7r2u00ByWjw",
5 times. May be it is just a dummy message.

I think you should try get on it
GET [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts/{encoded](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts/%7Bencoded) ugcPostUrn|shareUrn}?viewContext=AUTHOR

and you can see media order. I think media order stays same. It is just how LinkedIn is displaying it.

```
{
    "author": "urn:li:organization:5590506",
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
    "specificContent": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
            "media": [
                {
                    "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5500AQG7r2u00ByWjw",
                    "status": "READY",
                    "title": {
                        "attributes": [],
                        "text": "Sample Video Create"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "shareCommentary": {
                "attributes": [],
                "text": "Some share text"
            },
            "shareMediaCategory": "VIDEO"
        }
    },
    "targetAudience": {
        "targetedEntities": [
            {
                "locations": [
                    "urn:li:country:us",
                    "urn:li:country:gb"
                ],
                "seniorities": [
                    "urn:li:seniority:3"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "visibility": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Jin, I don't see this fitting in the JSON structure. The surrounding element is an object, not an array. Having multiple 'media' keys isnt valid as wel. Can you share the full JSON of what you mean? Thank you

Comment: LOL you sent the multiple media tags inside main media and i asked you to just keep one. try different media id it may work.